# Copy pasting worksheets to different workbooks (into a table)

Tags: vba, excel, copy

So I have two `Workbooks` : `w1` and `w2`

In `w1`, I have 5 `Worksheets` named:

- `france`
- `usa`
- `germany`
- `switzerland`
- `spain`

For each worksheet I have to copy Ranges: `Range("D2:S17")`, `Range ("AX2:BM17")`, `Range("AB2:AQ17")` and paste them into the `w2` which contains 5 empty worksheets with same worksheet names as `w1`.

So I want to do a vba macro that copies `Range("D2:S17")` in `w1.worksheets("france")` and pastes it into `w2.worksheets("france")` and when it pastes, give it automatically the name `"france_tab1"` and (`"germany_tab1"` in `worksheets("germany")` etc...)

and transform `(Range("D2:S17"))` when pasted to a `table(i,j)` (in order to do calculations after)

Comment: Can you please clean the post up? There are tags for code that would greatly help the readability.  Your English is fine, it's just a little hard to parse the code vs regular text.  Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can just loop thru the sheets to transfer data and change the names with:

```
Dim nameArray() As Variant
Dim resultArray() As Variant

nameArray = Array("france", "usa", "germany", "switzerland", "spain")

For each name in nameArray
    With w2.Worksheets(name)
        .Range("D2:S17").Value = w1.Worksheets(name).Range("D2:S17").Value
        .Range("AX2:BM17").Value = w1.Worksheets(name).Range("AX2:BM17").Value
        .Range("AB2:AQ17").Value = w1.Worksheets(name).Range("AB2:AQ17").Value
        .Name = .Name & "_tab1"

        resultArray = .Range("D2:S17").Value ' 2D array
        ' do array calculations here
    End With
Next
```